# Mark as unread button in email application?

Tags: email

is there a hidden "Mark as read" button I'm not aware of in the email app in Android?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This probably depends on the device, as devices with custom UIs (TouchWiz, Sense, Motoblur) will have different email applications. On CyanogenMod (and I believe vanilla Android) you simply tick the checkmark next to the message or messages you want and the button slides in from the bottom.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Is there an in-message button as well?

Comment: @Shimmy: Again, may vary, but on CyanogenMod/vanilla there should be a "Mark Read/Unread" button if you open an email and press the hard `Menu` button.